# How to open word documents using cordova Inappbrowser?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I struck with the opening word document, PPT by using cordova inappbrowser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal way to do this is to use plugins like `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` to download the file into device and `cordova-plugin-file-opener2` to open it using the default app in the device, for a specific file type.

If you really need to open it using a web view or inappbrowser, the best way would be to use external services like google docs. See following example

```
https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=https://www.unm.edu/~unmvclib/powerpoint/pptexamples.ppt
```